# How can I change the default button highlight in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

So I have this button:

[image]

And I need to remove that blue rectangle. I tried to add the following event triggers (IsMouseOver and IsFocused), and set the background transparent:

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="Border" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The button is inside this menu:

```
   <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <Button x:Name="OrderBy" Content="Order By" Width="75" Margin="0,8,0,0"  Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"/>
        <GridSplitter Height="20" Width="1" Background="Black" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="Refresh" Content="Refresh" Width="75" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Search" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Search" Width="240"  Margin="250,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Menu>
```

I am new to WPF and I already searched a lot to try to find an answer to this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite a ControlTemplate for MenuItem, namely TopLevelItemTemplate and set in Trigger for IsHighlighted Border's Background to transparent. The highlighting comes from MenuItem not from Button.
Try to put this to Resources of your Menu:

```
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

        <!-- Border Brushes -->

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <!-- Miscellaneous Brushes -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />


        <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}"
       TargetType="Separator">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!-- TopLevelHeader -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"
                 TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Border Name="Border" >
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Margin="6,3,6,3" 
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Bottom"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Border 
          Name="SubmenuBorder"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel  
            IsItemsHost="True" 
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
              Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <!-- TopLevelItem -->

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Border Name="Border" >
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Margin="6,3,6,3" 
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- SubmenuItem -->

        <ControlTemplate 
  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Border Name="Border" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="Icon"
        Margin="6,0,6,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentSource="Icon"/>
                    <Border 
        Name="Check"  
        Width="13" Height="13" 
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="6,0,6,0" 
        Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                        <Path 
          Name="CheckMark"
          Width="7" Height="7" 
          Visibility="Hidden" 
          SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
          Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
          StrokeThickness="2"
          Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="HeaderHost"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
        Margin="5,2,0,2"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsCheckable" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Check" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
              Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- SubmenuHeader -->

        <ControlTemplate 
  x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}" 
  TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Border Name="Border" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="Icon"
        Margin="6,0,6,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ContentSource="Icon"/>
                    <ContentPresenter 
        Name="HeaderHost"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ContentSource="Header"
        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
        Margin="5,2,2,2"
        DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <Path 
        Grid.Column="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" 
        Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" />
                    <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Right"
        HorizontalOffset="-4" 
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Border 
          Name="SubmenuBorder"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <StackPanel  
            IsItemsHost="True" 
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
              Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- MenuItem Style -->

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```