# How to stop default WPF from overriding mouse hover function?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

In my C# WPF application, I have 3 buttons, each is assigned image brush backgrounds just after the InitializeComponent() function in the MainWindow Constructor.
 when I hover my mouse over each of the buttons, they turn to a solid blue colour. I figured I needed to add MouseEnter methods to each button, along with MouseLeave ones. changing the button to a darker version when hovered.

But the image still turns blue when hovered... See MP4 for explanation

https://i.gyazo.com/06d936daaf5153c369b2b9af2faa1a9f.mp4

Thank You

J

Comment: you cann override Button Template. See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630968/wpf-c-sharp-button-style)

Comment: If It's a listview you can just disable selection on the listview or use ItemsControl

Comment: No code changes are required.  You simply need to define a custom template, as Stefan says.  The default template changes the background based on the state of the button, and it only respects the background when it's in its 'normal' state.  Follow the link he provided for an example.

Comment: @Stefan i don't see which part of your linked post is non code related?

Comment: it was "here" ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630968/wpf-c-sharp-button-style

Comment: i don't understand?

Comment: It can be helpfully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740207/how-can-i-change-the-default-button-highlight-in-wpf-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use following **Style** on **Buttons** to achieve the required outcome , In case you need to use another color on mouse over just change the border foreground property within trigger below , in case if dont want any of mouse over effect then just change the foreground to Transperent

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>               
     <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                       <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                      </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                         </Trigger>
             </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
```